# Learn How To Develop GUI Applications

Tags: user-interface

I'm learning Objective-C and already know many other languages, but every time that i try to develop GUI applications i stuck, because i didn't understand and mental visualize the application running and those coordinates of the buttons and the other objects always let me confused, but where i can learn how to do good GUI applications using only my codes(without any type of IDE)? Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know if i choose the right words to describe my question, but every question about it please comment. Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the event (message) driven architecture? See for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644927%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: In my opinion, good GUI applications do not position elements using coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest starting small and working your way up. Start off writing a simple Unit converter application with a GUI. Then maybe try something bigger like a minimal text editor (Open, edit the text, and save back out), and go from there.

Also, if you have a certain kind of application you really like, use it as an example and try to think how its developer made it. The great thing about Cocoa apps on the Mac is you can usually open up the actual interface files the application uses (right-click the Application bundle and select "Show Contents", navigate in there until you find .xib or .nib files, which usually can be opened by Interface Builder). Poke around in those to get an idea of how the apps work.

Finally, when you start building your applications (big or small) I highly suggest doing paper mockups. While using a tool on a computer is great, a blank sheet of paper has much less to get in your way. It's essentially your imagination and the paper. Start with a big rectangle (your Window) and draw in the interface. You'll get a feel of how things relate spatially. Don't focus too much on making the mockups pretty or detailed, but do focus on flow of the application and how you'd want it to be used.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start "thinking" about the application before actually developing it. How to navigate and access its functionalites **from the end user's perspective**, by doing wireframes / mockups. Use tools such as [balsamiq mockup](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) for that ([here](http://ciohappyhour.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/ultimate%20wireframing%20toolbox.html) are many other similar tools).

In the end, what you really want to do is look at the usability, and develop an approach to development that puts the end-user in the center of the creative process. There are some excellent free resources out there. My favourites are: [http://www.uxmatters.com/](http://www.uxmatters.com/index.php) and this book and blog [Designing Web Interfaces](http://designingwebinterfaces.com/)

Comment: Hi! the second link is obsolete! :)